# Surface plot with custom ranges in all three dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to generate a surface plot according to following criterion

Maximum value of x = .0022396698004215356

Minimum value of x = -.0022396698004215356

Maximum value of y = .0002880473016238141

Minimum value of Y = -.0002880473016238141

Whereas, the plot will be plotted using this formula:

Z = 1.64214226911672 * (1 - x^2/1.77762709862528 - y^2/0.228623294807122)^0.5

Here is the MWE which rather be called Minimum non working example. I have tried a lot of options but none seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false} 

\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={A test plot},
xlabel={a},
ylabel={b}, 
domain=-5:5,
samples=100,
colormap/jet
]
\addplot3[
mesh,
samples=40,
%domain=-8:8,
]
{sqrt(1000 - x^2 - y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to know a way to plot something like the figure given below:

[image: Target image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is too small even for `pgfplots` because of the squaring but your problem is homogenous hence scaling fortunately save you here and then you can change the labels etc. An example with scaled axis:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={A test plot},
xlabel={a},
ylabel={b}, 
domain = -0.0022396698004215356:0.0022396698004215356,
y domain=-0.0002880473016238141:0.0002880473016238141,
colormap/viridis
]
\addplot3[surf,samples=40]
{1.64214226911672 * (1 - (100*x)^2/1.77762709862528 -(100* y)^2/0.228623294807122)^0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And please don't use `jet` it is a wrong colormap.

[image]

Comment: Perfectly what I was looking for! Excellent solution. Thanks